# Как рассчитать ёмкостную сложность алгоритма?

Tags: c#

Как я понял, ёмкостная сложность измеряется в байтах. Есть ли в C# возможность посчитать эти байты во время выполнения программы? И можно ли вообще программно рассчитать сложность алгоритма сортировки? Или только посчитать количество циклов и представить в виде О большого?

Comment: Можно измерить потребление памяти во время каждого отдельного прогона. Но, ёмкостная сложность - функция, восстановить которую по отдельным прогонам можно только приближенно. Обычно проделывается некоторая теоретическая работа по анализу исходного кода. Результат этой работы - функция в нотации О-большого которая описывает как меняется потребление памяти в зависимости от размера сортируемого массива.